# Transform a boundary condition into polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose I have the boundary condition $u_y(x,0) = 0$. How can I transform it into polar coordinates?

$$
x= r\cos(\theta), y = r\sin(\theta),
$$
so
$$
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = ?
$$

I'm a little confused since I don't think I can use the chain rule here.

Comment: Real my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule you have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \cdot \frac{dr}{dy} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} \cdot \frac{d\theta}{dy}$$

Comment: so $\frac{\partial r}{\partial y} = \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sin\theta}$?

Comment: Yes.  In the end, you'll have an equation of the form $A \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + B \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} = 0$.  This equation holding on the boundary of the problem (which you can no longer simply describe as the line $y = 0$) is equivalent to the original boundary condition.